# Creating simple SIP service

Tags: php, linphone, sip-server

Recently I've discovered [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) which offers iOS SDK for creating VoIP calls. I would like to integrate it into my existing chat application and problem is that I need to make SIP service on my server which gives me a headaches. Is there any out of the box solution for this service which can be easily compiled and integrated with MySql database? 
I found [OpenSIPS](http://opensips.org/), [Kamailio](http://www.kamailio.org/w/) and [Asterisk](http://asterisk.org/) but since I'm new in this field they look very complicated at first. 
When you start Linphone example app you can create SIP user account using their free SIP service. 
I need to create similar service which can be used withing PHP script.

I have experience in UNIX / Linux and with server side programming (PHP & MySql) so even pointing me to a good tutorial would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A step by step tutorial about installing Kamailio with MySQL backend is available at:

- http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/install/4.1.x/git

There is a web admin application named Siremis written in PHP that can be used for management of users as GUI.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've already seen installation Kamailio with MySql but I didn't know that Siremis exists. I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: @miconda Does kamailio allow new user registration through the client? I want to use linphone as a client. I want visitors to register/signup through the client and start using the service. I mean the admin do not have to create a subscriber manually.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this control-panel for OpenSIPs help you :
      https://github.com/OpenSIPS/opensips-cp 
another link can be:
      https://github.com/ideawu/phpvoip